# How to get the widget in QLayout under the mouse by Drag&drop?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop

I build a widget which accepts drag&drop as follows:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget( QWidget *p_parent ) : QFrame( p_parent )
{
    setAcceptDrops( true );
    m_layout = new QLayout( this );  //this is layout of my custom widget
    layout->setSpacing( 0 );

    m_indicator = new QWidget( this );
    m_indicator->setObjectName( "indicator" );
    m_indicator->setFixedWidth( 5 );
    layout->addWidget( m_indicator );
    ....
    ....
 }

 void MyWidget::dragMoveEvent( QDragMoveEvent *p_event )
 {
    p_event->acceptProposedAction();
 }
```

My main job is to insert the dragged object into the layout, therefore, I should identify which item is under the mouse, and do my job after that. In function `dragMoveEvent` above, I can do `p_event->pos()` to get the position of the mouse. But `QLayout` does not have method `itemAt(int x, int y)`. What should I do now?

Comment: @hyde: thank you, I just too focused on the layout, and forget about the parent widget :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layouts can't do that, but fortunately [the parent widget can](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#childAt). Example code (untested):

```cpp
void MyWidget::dragMoveEvent( QDragMoveEvent *p_event )
 {
    auto *widget = childAt(p_event->pos());
    if(widget) {
        ....
 }
```